# How to access request/params, etc. with Spring Boot and Groovy templates

Tags: groovy, spring-boot, template-engine

I have a Groovy Template login.tpl file resembling:

```
layout 'layout.tpl', title: 'LOGIN',
        content: contents {
//          if(param.logout) p class: "alert", "You have been logged out"
//          if(param.error) p class: "alert alert-error", "There was an error, please try again"
            form id: 'loginForm', class: 'form-horizontal',
                    role: 'form', action: '/login', method: 'post', {
                // BLAH here
            }
        }
```

This is basically translated from the Spring Boot sample-web-secure starter version, which uses Thymeleaf.

How can I access intrinsics like request/response/session, etc.? Do I need to hack up an intermediate controller that puts this stuff into the model by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring exposes a `RequestContext` to template views (see `AbstractTemplateView`). In Spring Boot 1.1 it is called "spring". In 1.2 it uses the default name from Spring MVC: "springMacroRequestContext".

Comment: Actually, I accepted this too soon. Tried 'p "${springMacroRequestContext}"' and it returned null. Is there any example code to show how to use this in a Groovy template?

Comment: I tried 'p "${spring.request.serverName}"' and it worked. Using 1.2.0.M2.